# How to configure properly Identity core with DI on net.core 3.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I started a pet project on `ASP.NET core 3.1` created `MVC` project and a bunch of libraries to work with.

I also created :

- `User`,
- `Role`,
- `RoleManager`
- `UserManager`

Classes which are inherited from `AspNetCore.Identity`. But I've got a problem while including those classes into `DI container`. Every time i get this `InvalidOpertationException` with info: *Unable to resolve service for type `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore` while attempting to activate `JournalUserManager`*.

Here's my code sample:

```
`services.AddIdentityCore<JournalUser>(options =>
 {
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
 })
   .AddRoles<JournalRole>()
   .AddRoleManager<JournalRoleManager>()
   .AddUserManager<JournalUserManager>();`
```

Any suggestions how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [custom storage providers guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

In the **Reconfigure app to use a new storage provider** there is this example of setting up the `IUserStore` and the `IRoleStore`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add identity types
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    // Identity Services
    services.AddTransient<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, CustomUserStore>();
    services.AddTransient<IRoleStore<ApplicationRole>, CustomRoleStore>();
    string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    services.AddTransient<SqlConnection>(e => new SqlConnection(connectionString));
    services.AddTransient<DapperUsersTable>();

    // additional configuration
}
```